# How can I enable PDF support in gdal?

Tags: gdal, geopdf

I've installed GDAL2.3dev on my mac using Homebrew, expecting it to support GeoPDFs already. But when I run `gdalinfo` on a pdf file from USGS, I still get this error:

ERROR 4: `WA_Sunrise_244132_1971_24000_geo.pdf' not recognized as a supported file format.

What do I need to do add PDF support to GDAL?

Comment: you need the libraries Poppler,PoDoFo PDFium http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html

Comment: On Windows an interpreter like GhostScript https://www.ghostscript.com/ is required to rasterize the pdf into an image.. I'm not sure about Macs. There is instructions https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56f6ee5f8a65e2431330aac8/t/5740e1273c44d80a9c302130/1463869743756/geopdf2geotiff_GDAL.pdf that might illuminate. First check your formats with **gdalinfo --formats** and see if your build supports PDF.

Comment: You can't add support afterwards but GDAL must be compiled with some of the abovementioned libraries. Check with "gdalinfo --formats" if your build is really made without PDF driver.

Comment: @Mapperz I have Poppler installed but I don't know how to build a package from scratch, which is why I've been using Homebrew. I can see that others have had the same problem and were able to fix it by ./configure the Poppler path before ./make the build but I don't know how to incorporate that into Homebrew builds.

Comment: homebrew poppler install http://macappstore.org/poppler/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac) has shifted to a new strategy for PDF support. You now need to install `gdal2-pdf`:

`$ brew install gdal2-pdf`

and then, as brew tells you to, link to the plugins:

`$ export GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins`

Peter

Comment: Thanks Peter - I tried that but I'm still getting the same problem. Perhaps I need to uninstall the previous gdal installation?

Comment: I still get the same error even when I explicitly invoke the new instance of gdalinfo that came with this new install: `/usr/local/Cellar/gdal2/2.2.2_1/bin/gdalinfo WA_Sunrise_244132_1971_24000_geo.pdf `

Comment: This worked after I uninstalled all my gdal installations and just ran brew install gdal2-pdf, hooray!

Comment: @ZenLiu glad to hear it! You can use `brew link` to choose which gdal you call when in the shell. Not sure if you tried that first.